# I'm using Apollo Client and i'm getting Unhandled Rejection error when Mutating data

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, apollo-client

```
    import {gql,useQuery,useMutation} from '@apollo/client'
import {useRef,useState} from 'react'
const AUTHORS = gql`
query {
    authors {
        name
        id
    }
}
` 
const ADDBOOK = gql`
mutation AddBook($title:String!,$genre:String!,$authorId:String!){
    addBook(title:$title, genre:$genre, authorId:$authorId){
        title
        genre
        authorId
    }
}
`

const AddBook = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState()
    const [genre, setGenre] = useState()
    const {loading, error, data , refetch} = useQuery(AUTHORS)
    const [addBook, { data:newBook }] = useMutation(ADDBOOK)
    
    const selectRef = useRef()
    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        const authorId = selectRef.current.value
        e.preventDefault()
            addBook({
                variables:{title,genre,authorId}
            })
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="title">Book's Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" onChange={(e)=>{setTitle(e.target.value)}}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="genre">Book's genre</label>
          <input type="text" name="genre" onChange={(e)=>{setGenre(e.target.value)}}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <select name="author" ref={selectRef} >
              <option>select Author</option>
              {!loading && data.authors.map(author=>{return <option key={author.id} value={author.id} >{author.name}</option>})}
          </select>
        </div><br/>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddBook;
```

when i try to mutate i get an error : Unhandled Rejection (Error): Response not successful: Received status code 400,

i'm using Apollo Console in the front-end and it seems that the mutation works fine but my code isn't giving the server the right data for some reason

Comment: exact **network** request and response ... tested in playground using query variables? exactly the same query shape?

Comment: oh! i messed  up there , the query was wrong , i requested an authorId which wasn't a valid query , thank you!